# Angular js $location.path not reloading same page if we hit refresh(F5)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, single-page-application, angular-routing

We have single page application with 3 controllers. In root controller we will check user exist or not and redirect to landing controller using **$location.path**.
when user is in landing page and hit refresh(F5), angular code execution is like below

landing controller code-->root code ,here it will hit $location.path but it is not reloading landing controller  as hash tag is same as location.path

If we use **$route.reload**, it is reloading the landing controller on refresh. but asynch http post servise call in landing page calling twice and showing wrong results in landing page.

please help me in resolving this

**Root Controller Code:**

```
$scope.init = function () {      

    $http.get("/Home/CheckUserExisits").success(function (data) {   

                $location.path('/Landing');               
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

**Landing Controller:**

```
$scope.init = function () {      
$http.post("/Landing/count", test, config).success(function (data) {
       some process...
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

Comment: you should add some code , so that we can find the issue.

Comment: As far as your coding goes it is doing exactly as what is supposed to do. As soon as refresh is clicked previous scope is gone and redoing the user verification. If you have already verified user once keep some sort of primary key or flag in session and use that in root to redirect to the landing

Comment: we want user check need to be done and with latest input values in root it should redirect to landing when we click F5, but if we are on landing page and hitting F5 this is not happening, but if we are in some other page from root it is redirecting properly to landing with latest values.